# Get the text written in the onchange event handler

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I'm trying to retrieve the text that I've written in the onchange attribute of my input tag.

For eg:

```
   <input type="text" id="test1" name="test1" onchange="some_js_func();" />
```

I want to retrieve the value of the onchange, i.e, "some_js_func();" on load of my html page.

I've tried the following to access this in the same way as we access any value for an hmtl element using getElementById() function:

```
 var myvar = document.getElementById("test1").change;
```

However the above code returns undefined.

Is there any way to get the value of the onchange as a string using only javascript and not jQuery or other client side scripting language?

I want the following specific text only: "some_js_func();"

Comment: `document.getElementById("test1").onchange;`

Comment: To be clear, you want the acual text `"some_js_func();"` correct?

Comment: yes, Spencer Wieczorek. I've edited my question

Comment: Not exactly related, but usually these things are detected with Dev Tools. Just hit F12 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
document.getElementById("test1").getAttribute("onchange");
```

The `getAttribute()` method will get the value of an attribute for the element.

Comment: [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)'s contain properties for each html attribute on the tag, you don't need to use `.getAttribute()` you can just call `.onchange`

Comment: @Teemu that he wants to get the value inside the onchange attribute of an HTML element?

Comment: @iam-decoder Yes, the exact value written in the HTML, not a function reference nor a string implementation of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.getAttribute()`:

```js
//Out input element:
var myElem = document.getElementById("test1");
//Here, the appended text node has the same value as the string inputted into the onchange attribute in the HTML:
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myElem.getAttribute("onchange")));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test1" name="test1" onchange="some_js_func();">
```